# grub menu is not loading any operating system

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi

I have recently installed ubuntu 20.04 as a dual boot over Windows 10 operating system. The Windows OS is as usual in `C:\` drive, and Ubuntu has been installed `E:\` after formating it. So, I believe, Windows 10 is safe in `C:\`.

**Problem:**

while I am selecting any operating system, Ubuntu or, Windows 10 from the grub menu, the menu is just reloading, without loading any of these operating system.

**Tried:**
I tried to launch the Ubuntu Recovery mode from the `grub -> Advanced Ubuntu` option, luckily it was working. But after restarting the computer, the grub menu is behaving the same not loading any of these two OS.

In the order of grub menu: (1) Ubuntu (2) Windows 10.

I google, most of the problems are about grub menu visibility, but did not find any solution about my case.

Comment: Please boot Windows directly. If it works then take the time to disable its Fast Startup feature and shutdown, not reboot to make it stick. Then again make sure all pending updates are fully installed. Then change the boot order back to Ubuntu (Grub) and try again to both either one. Report back.

Comment: How I can boot windows directly? I cannot start the windows OS at all.

Comment: Hit Esc (or some other key indicated by your system) during early startup, then select "Boot Menu", then select "Windows". The names might be a bit different than that, but the correct options should be evident.

Comment: Or simply opening UEFI settings > Boot and change the boot order there. This is troubleshooting 101.

Answer (score 3):

Under Ubuntu, let GRUB to generate new config.

First, backup the existing configuration to be able to get back if needed

```
sudo cp -r /boot/efi /backup/
```

supposing the /backup/ folder exists. Either create it or use different destination.

Then generate new GRUB config files

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should also find Windows on another partition and add a working option into the GRUB menu.

Then reboot the PC and choose the desired option.

**Update:** This solution could have worked, if the boot mode was UEFI. But from the comments/chat below, it seems it is probably not the case.

Comment: cp: cannot stat '/boot/efi' : no such file or directory

Comment: reinstalling the ubuntu, now ubuntu I can load from grub menu, but windows is not loading, and same as old problem if select windows, grub menu repeats.

Comment: Then, the problem is more deep. You have no mount point for EFI system partition (ESP). Is your machine physical, or virtual? Also, os grub in UEFI mode or legacy mode? You can tell by going to grub command line (by pressing "c" when in grub menu) and then executing command "echo $grub_platform". GRUB shell will show "pc" in BIOS mode "efi" in UEFI mode.

Comment: my machine is physical

Comment: I tried `echo $grub_platform` shows `pc`

Comment: OK, you have Ubuntu in legacy mode. Now you need to check, which mode was your Windows installed. Both OS's must be in the same mode in order to get it work. Go to PC BIOS setup, change the boot order or mode to get the Windows to boot directly (as suggested also under your question). You can also try enabling/disabling UEFI or Legacy, or change CSM support, if available, or other options under Boot section.

Comment: After you  get your Windows to boot, check you Windows boot mode by pressing Win+R or opening terminal window by calling 'cmd.exe', executing 'msinfo32.exe' and under System Summary on the left, check the value of BIOS mode item on the right (should be either UEFI or Legacy).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136632/discussion-between-ethcz-and-bimo).